# bash housekeeing script needed permission to delete different folders and files in folder

Tags: linux, bash, unix

we are going to create a housekeeping script in e.g. PARENT_FOLDER.
In PARENT_FOLDER there will be many different folders and files with different owners.

Please let me know what would be the proper permission solution for this scenarion. I assume the better is to set +wx on PARENT_FOLDER, but I'd like to ensure this is the only option as security is the most important thing for me.

Thanks, 
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to assign the correct permission to the folder that you are going to manage. If you will only bye the administrator of the directory PARENT_FOLDER then you should assign the permission (rwx-r-x-r-x). (chmod 775 PARENT_FOLDER)
Then with the sub-directories you have to assign the permissions you want for each user and add the folder to each user with chown -user -directory.
So in this way every user will have only access to edit their own files in his directory.